# Image Blob is >50 times its size after upload

Tags: javascript, image, blob, todataurl

I'm really dumbfounded as to what is happenning here.

I'm using [Preprocess.js](https://github.com/josefrichter/resize/blob/master/public/preprocess.js) to resize/compress an image on the front-end side. Except that, in the processfile() function on the image.onload (line 32), I'm converting the toDataURL() string to a Blob, so I can send it out as a file object to the API. To do this, I'm using the [dataURItoBlob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5100158/357813) function. I end up with this :

```
  image.onload = function() {

    var resized = resizeMe(image, fileinput, max_width, max_height);
    var blob = dataURItoBlob(resized);
    eventImages[0] = blob;

  }
```

I then send out the eventImage's content to the API.

Now, this works great. It resizes/compresses the image, it gets sent out to the API (with a success response) and I can see the output image within a webpage.

What happens though, is that in Chrome/Firefox's consoles (Resources tab), the image weight is quite big (8MB in Chrome, 1,5MB in Firefox).

What's even stranger is this: if I load the image within a webpage, it loads as if it was its compressed size. But if I load it from its direct link from the API, it takes a while to load and show up (as if it was loading 8MB/1,5MB of data).

What's going on here? Is it all on the front-end side? Is there something glitchy with browsers, the API, or a MIME/Content-type?

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Bug was fixed. It was due to server regression on the API side. Code above is all good. Thanks!